# How to get the count of each distinct value in a column using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a table as shown below

[Db Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XCZF.png)

what I tried is to return distinct

```
var result = db.TaskTable.Select(item => item.Status).Distinct().Count();
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
return Ok(json);
```

Using Link for my web API I want to return the distinct count of each. for example in user_goup A I want to return it as:

> {
> "Ongoing:" "2"
> "Completed": "1"
> "Stopped": "1" }

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like:

```
var q = from item db.TaskTable
        group by item.Status into byStatus
        select new {Status = byStatus.Key, Count = byStatus.Distinct().Count() };
```

Then construct the JSON manually from the result.

Comment: You can use the fluent api `.ToDictionary(i => i.Status, i => i.Count)` to format the json result from the `IQuerable`. Not sure if there's a linq sql format for that.